# Ethereum wallets that support “Custom RPC URL”

Tags: ethereum, rpc, wallet, metamask

I'm running a private blockchain and I've been using Metamask connected to my custom RPC URL with no issues.. I'm curious if there's any other Ethereum wallet that let's you add and connect to a custom RPC URL.

Comment: Consider posting to the Ethereum StackExchange site: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are not that many wallets that allow to connect to random networks. MetaMask tends to be the only one.

Your best bet is to try here https://walletconnect.org/wallets - also some of the wallets are open source, so you can add this custom functionality to these wallets yourself.

Comment: Ok, got it.
Does hardware wallets like Legder/Trezor provide a functionality to add custom RPC URL?

Comment: I do not know answer for that - you need to test out yourself

Answer (score 1):

I noticed when I opened Alphawallet iOS app, in the last month that a new Custom RPC function was available in the settings section.

I basically went to Settings, Active Networks, there's now a (+) button where I could insert the url for a custom rpc I was testing for interoperability of my token contracts on different networks (eth and polygon and the custom url). So you could try them? Not sure about private blockchains though.